# Event for printing every page

Tags: c#, printing

I'm trying to get the number of pages the print job is printing and I tried using `TotalPages` from `Win32_PrintJob` but it does not give the right number of pages printed.

Is there a way that I can monitor an event every time the printer prints a single page? I could just use a counter to count the total number of pages.

Here is my code for getting the number of pages printed, but it does not give me the right numbers.

```
 public void getNumberofPages() {
  string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob";
  ManagementObjectSearcher searchPrintJobs = new ManagementObjectSearcher(searchQuery);
  ManagementObjectCollection prntJobCollection = searchPrintJobs.Get();
  foreach(ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection) {
   Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    lblPrinterdPages.Text = prntJob.Properties["TotalPages"].Value.ToString();
   });
  }
 }
```

Comment: Pretty vague.  Are you trying to get this for something your app is printing or are you just wanting to monitor a printer (not *the* printer)

Comment: i'm monitoring a printer, i already have an event listener via event logs so i can already monitor every time a user prints a document. now what i only need is to get how many pages the user prints.